# how to call an activity of a task from an activity of another task

Tags: android

If, there is an activity task with activities

```
A1 -> A2
```

and another activity task with activities

```
B1 -> B2
```

The requirement is, From `B2` I need to call `A2`, but no new instance of `A2` must be created, it should be loaded from the `stack` (`A2` which is in top of the first task)
Now when I press `back button` from `A2` I need to get `A1`?
How to implement this?

Answer (score 2):

Have you read [Tasks and Back Stack](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/tasks-and-back-stack.html)?

There is an option for activity:
**"singleTask"**
The system creates a new task and instantiates the activity at the root of the new task. However, if an instance of the activity already exists in a separate task, the system routes the intent to the existing instance through a call to its `onNewIntent()` method, rather than creating a new instance. Only one instance of the activity can exist at a time.

Comment: But here 2 tasks are involved.
What I knew is that, "singleTask" is related to just 1 task.

SO, how should I call an activity of another task with flag, "single task" ?

Comment: Just start A2 activity from B2. In A2 implement onNewIntent() and that's all. If A2 exists then onNewIntent() is invoked in other case onCreate().

Comment: A2 is not a root here. If we declare launchmode as "SingleTask" or "SingleInstance" then A2 will be root of the task. But please note here that, my A2 is at the top of its task. So how can I call its "onNewTntent()" by simply calling it. Can you make it clear ?

Comment: Look at the Figure 4. in the link that I posted.